# Sometimes Rsync fails to copy files from the remote machine

Tags: perl, tcl, rsync, expect

```
#Bypassing the ssh
spawn -noecho /usr/bin/ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' "$user\@$ip"; 

if { $argc == $total_arguments} {
set REMOTEDIR "$remote_dir";

spawn -noecho rsync -r $user\@$ip:$destination/* $remote_dir
expect "Password:"
}
```

Above is part of the code where i am copying files from the remote machine to my home directory. But while executing the script it sometimes fail to copy all the files.
What could be the reason for failure and how to validate whether it copied all the files or not??

Answer (score 1):

For validation:

If you want to check if all files were copied, you can do a simple glob or list for list of files in the remote dir. Then compare to the glob list of files in the target dir.

```
set globResult [ exec rsh -l $user $host "cd $dir; ls -l | wc -l" ]
```

Or if you go further, you can always checksum on both the remote and the target directory.

As for the reason for failure, it could've been network or server issues.
While you are doing rsync, have you check the return exit status to make sure rsync has completed successfully?